# found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when try to hidden navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a problem. I want to make if the cell tapped on 1st table view, it will display 2nd view controller and the navigation bar is hidden. Then i go back to 1st view controller using button with code:

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("restaurant")
    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but it print out

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

in 2nd view controller, I hidden the navigation bar using this:

```
    func hiddenNavBar(){

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

and show the navigation bar again on 1st view controller using :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    createNavBar()
}

func createNavBar(){

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
}
```

my Main storyboard looks like this:
[image]

Comment: check storyboard identifier "restaurant"

Comment: already set the storyboard ID

Comment: check if both are same string or not

Comment: it has same string

Comment: are you presenting viewcontroller on back button? instead use popViewCOntroller method

Comment: Great Thanks! I think popViewController is used when the view controller linked with segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong way to go back to previous view controller.
If you are using navigation view controller to push the second view controller then you need to pop view controller using 
`self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

How UINavigationViewController works?
It creates a stack to keep track of all the view controllers you push that why if you want to go back, simply you need to pop view controller from the top as stack works.

Answer (score 0):

Write ? instead of ! in navigationbarhidden line.

Like this,

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true